# How to show the Key value from Array in descending order?

Tags: php

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php

    $toplist = array("Name1" => 1,"Name2" => 2,"Name3" => 3,"Name4" => 4,"Name5" => 5,"Name6" => 6,"Name7" => 7,"Name8" => 8,"Name9" => 9,"Name10" => 10);

    rsort($toplist);

    $length = count($toplist);

    for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
        echo $toplist[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

**And the output I get:**

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

**But, I want the key from the value.**
**Like this output:**

```
Name10
Name9
Name8
Name7
Name6
Name5
Name4
Name3
Name2
Name1
```

Comment: You could use `array_search` but it doesn't make much sense...what does this array represent? You seem to be looping with a numerical index when you have an associative array. Why not just do `foreach($toplist as $key => $value) { echo $value; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this, first `rsort()` will reset the keys of the data, so use  [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) instead.  The second part can be done using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to fetch the keys of the array and output these values instead.

```
arsort($toplist);
$length = count($toplist);
$keylist = array_keys($toplist);
for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
    echo $keylist[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This results in...

```
Name10
Name9
Name8
Name7
Name6
Name5
Name4
Name3
Name2
Name1
```

You could simplify your output using `foreach()`...

```
arsort($toplist);
foreach ( $toplist as $key=>$value )    {
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";
}
```